# How to select a list variable from several list variables based on multiple keywords, for a deployed application?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to figure out how to select a list variable from several list variables. In the web application I'm focusing, a user account has an "account type" and several "permissions" associated. So I have a BBD-styled test case:

```
Scenario:Manager without permission should not access
    Given I have a manager account
    And I can edit things
    And I cannot update things
    When ...
```

In this case there's 3 pre-conditions, and I want to choose a user account based on them. So if I have these:

```
@{user1}    john    accountant    edit_permission    update_permission
@{user2}    mary    manager    create_permission    edit_permission
@{user3}    clark    manager    create_permission    edit_permission
```

Then @{user3} is selected, because it's the only one that satisfies all conditions. Is it feasible or advisable to do this without resorting to variable files? The reason is I want to make the test cases as reusable as possible, so I don't want to tie test cases to particular variables which represent specific users.

EDIT: I'm using RF with Selenium2Library to test a deployed web app, and the users available in the web app may change over time. So I figured that perhaps it's more maintainable to be able to dynamically pick a user based on a set of keywords, since then I could just change the users in RF to match the ones available in the web app, rather than change several test cases or keywords. Another way could be to select a user from a set of keywords, if possible. If a set of keywords are given that characterizes the user (such as in the previous example), then I could give one based on the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're testing a live application and don't have the luxury of creating accounts specifically for test, I would say that the approach is feasible. In fact, I'm not sure you have any other choice if your goal is to write a zero-maintenance test.

What I would do is start with the concept that your "When I ..." keywords simply pull an account from a list of available accounts. This could be a test-level list or a suite-level list, depending on your needs. In other words, it would have no logic about picking the right account, it would just use one from a pre-built list -- either always picking the first one, or maybe always picking a random one.

So, that's the first step. Have your validation keywords depend on a list of accounts that they can pick from, with no knowledge of what's actually in that list.

Next, have your other keywords act as filters on that list. Perhaps the list starts as all possible accounts, or some subset of all accounts that you know you want to use for testing. When you call "Given I have a manager account", it would remove from the list all accounts that are not manager accounts. At this point, any keyword that needs an account would pull from the list, and would be guaranteed to only get manager accounts.

If you next call the keyword "And I can edit things", it would again remove accounts from the list, this time removing accounts that cannot edit things. From that point forward, any keyword that needs an account could pick from the list and only get managers that can edit things.

If you call "And I cannot update things", it would again remove items from the list. This time it would remove any items in the account list that can update things. You are then left with a list that is a) a manger, b) can edit things, and c) cannot update things.

By implementing these as filters, you can use them in any order, and combine them in any way you want:

```
Given I have a manager account
And I can update things
```

-or-

```
Given I can cannot update things
And I have a manager account
And I cannot edit things
```

... and so on.

Comment: I'm using RF with Selenium2Library to test a deployed web app, and the users available in the web app may change over time. So I figured that perhaps it's more maintainable to be able to dynamically pick a user based on a set of keywords, since then I could just change the users in RF to match the ones available in the web app, rather than change several test cases or keywords. 


Another way could be to select a user from a set of keywords, if possible. If a set of keywords are given that characterizes the user (such as in the previous example), then I could give one based on the keywords.

Comment: @user3605138: you might want to edit your question to mention that you're running tests against a live application. That is an important distinction.

Comment: @user3605138: I've rewritten my answer based on your response.

Comment: Indeed that's how I want to implement, use a set of conditions to filter out the list of users, but I don't know exactly how to do that in Robot Framework, since I'm a beginner with RF.